# Opencv : Conversion Mat to IplImage for cvLabel

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, iplimage

I have:

```
Mat *depthImage = new Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
```

And further in my code I do:

```
Mat image = *depthImage;
```

I do some OpenCV stuff with it and then I want to use `cvBlob` (so blob analysis). Though this function still uses `IplImage` and not `Mat`. So I wanted to convert them. I've read that I could just do this:

```
 IplImage *blobimg = image;
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
Semantic Issue: No viable conversion from 'cv::Mat' to 'IplImage *' (aka '_IplImage *')
```

Eventually I want to be able to use this function on the newley created `IplImage`

```
cvLabel(<#const IplImage *img#>, <#IplImage *imgOut#>, <#CvBlobs &blobs#>)
```

As you can see the conversion from `Mat` to `IplImage` is required. But it is not working. My question is how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html first entry

Comment: as you can see in my explanation i did that 'IplImage ipl_img =img'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin Beckett says in the comments, the cheatsheet shows this solution.  There is no conversion from `cv::Mat` to `IplImage *`, but there is a conversion from `cv::Mat` to `IplImage`.

Change the line

```
IplImage *blobimg = image;
```

to

```
IplImage blobimg = image;
```

and it should compile.

When calling `cvLabel`, pass the parameter like

```
cvLabel(&blobimg, ...);
```